# Scrapy crawler will not crawl any webpages

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

I have been trying to get this crawler working but I keep getting errors.
Can anyone suggest any ways to get it to run?

The main spider code is

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import Spider
from scrapy.selector import Selector


class gameSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = "game_spider.py"
allowed_domains = ["*"]
start_urls = [
    "http://www.game.co.uk/en/grand-theft-auto-v-with-gta-online-3-500-000-1085837?categoryIdentifier=706209&catGroupId="
]

def parse(self, response):
    sel = Selector(response)
    sites = sel.xpath('//ul[@class="directory-url"]/li')
    items = []

    for site in sites:
        item = Website()
        item['name'] = site.xpath('//*[@id="details301149"]/div/div/h2/text()').extract()
        """item['link'] = site.xpath('//a/@href').extract()
        item['description'] = site.xpath('//*[@id="overview"]/div[3]()').re('-\s[^\n]*\\r')"""
        items.append(item)

    print items
    return items
```

The item code is

```
import scrapy


class GameItem(Item):
    name = Field()
    pass
```

Comment: @danmash is right. You may be dealing with a dynamic page. Look in to [Waits](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/waits.html)

Comment: OK thanks both that helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `start_urls` link returns erorr 500.
There's no items.

```
In [7]: sites = response.xpath('//ul[@class="directory-url"]/li')

In [8]: sites
Out[8]: []
```